# with 4.15.0-91 kernel 32bit on dell latitude E6500 wifi not working. with -88 is ok

Tags: 18.04, kernel, kubuntu

With Kubuntu 18.04, I  installed last change 4.15.0-91 kernel 32bit on dell latitude E6500, but WiFi fails. With the older kernel 4.15.0-88 it works OK. This dell model has an extra button on right side to enable and disable wifi.

Kubuntu 18.04 extra driver 
product: BCM4322 802.11a/b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller

lshw: 
91 kernel  bad

```
    *-network           
         description: Ethernet interface
         product: 82567LM Gigabit Network Connection
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 19
         bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
         logical name: eth0
         version: 03
         serial: 00:24:e8:e8:e5:35
         capacity: 1Gbit/s
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
         configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=1.7-7 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
         resources: irq:24 memory:f6ae0000-f6afffff memory:f6adb000-f6adbfff ioport:efe0(size=32)
```

### *-usb:0

```
       *-network UNCLAIMED
            description: Network controller
            product: BCM4322 802.11a/b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller
            vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.0
            version: 01
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
            configuration: latency=0
            resources: memory:f69fc000-f69fffff
    *-pci:2
         description: PCI bridge
         product: 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 3
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1c.2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.2
```

88 kernel is working:

```
    *-network           
         description: Ethernet interface
         product: 82567LM Gigabit Network Connection
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 19
         bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
         logical name: eth0
         version: 03
         serial: 00:24:e8:e8:e5:35
         capacity: 1Gbit/s
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
         configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=1.7-7 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
         resources: irq:24 memory:f6ae0000-f6afffff memory:f6adb000-f6adbfff ioport:efe0(size=32)
```

### *-usb:0

```
       *-network
            description: Wireless interface
            product: BCM4322 802.11a/b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller
            vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.0
            logical name: wlan0
            version: 01
            serial: 90:4c:e5:3f:34:cc
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
            configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) ip=192.168.1.101 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11                                                                                                              
            resources: irq:17 memory:f69fc000-f69fffff                                                                          
    *-pci:2
         description: PCI bridge
         product: 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 3
         vendor: Intel Corporation
```

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Please also run _sudo lshw|grep -A15 'network\|Wireless'_ , highlight and copy the resulting text,  then come back here.  Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: It is Kubuntu, lsw 18.04